# c++ - matrix initialization with comma-separated values

Tags: c++

Hi I came across this piece of [code](http://dlib.net/matrix_ex.cpp.html). It demonstrates how to work with matrix structures of the dlib library.

According to this one can initialize a matrix structure by:

```
M = 54.2,  7.4,  12.1,
    1,     2,    3,
    5.9,   0.05, 1;
```

How can this be possible in C++?

Is this some kind of operator overloading?

Comment: For the sake of your readers' sanity, I suggest you don't try to imitate this monstrosity. I'd recommend using `std::initialiser_list` giving `M = {...};`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Logic

This is possible by overloading `operator,` (operator comma), and for example make it push new floating point values into `M`.

A thing to notice is that `operator,` should always have at least one parameter of class type, therefore you'll have to create a class that is implicitly convertible to floating point value (for example via a non `explicit` constructor with 1 argument of type `double` or `float`).

#### Example

For example we'll try to do this for a wrapper type over an `std::vector` and we'll try to make `M = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` a valid expression which results in an `std::vector` with those elements in sequence. You'll see that this is easily applicable to the matrix example you gave.

A thing to remember is that `operator=` has more precedence over `operator,` (as shown in [this table of operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)); therefore `M = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` will really be parsed as: `(((((M = 1), 2), 3), 4), 5)`.

Given that, we'll start by creating our class `container` with an `operator=` that takes a single value and pushes it into the container:

```
template<typename ValueType>
struct container {
    
    explicit container(std::size_t n) {
        vec.reserve(n);
    }
    
    container& operator=(ValueType a) {
        vec.push_back(a);
        return (*this);
    }

    std::vector<ValueType> vec;
    
};
```

At this point we can define `operator,` as:

```
template<typename ValueType>
container<ValueType>& operator,(container<ValueType>& m, ValueType a) {
    m.vec.push_back(a);
    return m;
}
```

which just pushes back a new element value.

And now you can easily see that the following works just fine and prints `1 2 3 4 5`:

```
int main() {
    container<int> M(5);
    M = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5;
    for (auto i : M.vec) std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb9a6af5f472689b)

#### Considerations

I discourage this technique as much as possible. It forces you to have weird semantic for other operators, such as `operator=` and really seem to add nothing to a simple use of `std::initializer_list<T>`.

A saner example would be to have `operator=` as follows:

```
container& operator=(std::initializer_list<ValueType> a) {
    std::copy(begin(a), end(a), back_inserter(vec)); 
    return (*this);
}
```

and then simply use brackets:

```
int main() {
    container<int> M(5);
    M = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    for (auto i : M.vec) std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecd78e93b67e5147)

Comment: how do you know the shape (3,3)?

Comment: @RuggeroTurra It's passed to the constructor in the initialization of the object `M` at `matrix<double> M(3,3);`.

Comment: THis is why the C people hate C++

Comment: @paulm This is also why C++ people hate C++ written by people who overload `operator,`

Comment: Many thanks Jefffrey! Clearly though, such pieces of code indicate a kind of mental instability :-)

Comment: @Nfys Glad to hear! By the way, I have update my answer to give a more in-depth example.

Comment: Btw, such initialization is used by [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), although using an extraction operator, like `M << 1,2,3,4,5,6;`. Not a big fan either.

Comment: No one is a fan of overloading the , operator. But it's the best option available for this prior to c++11

Comment: For added silliness, `operator,()` could also be defined as `return m = a;` in this example, unless I'm missing something.