# Matrix multiplication value assigning using dlib::matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-keyword, dlib

This works (matrix addition)

```
dlib::matrix<double, 2, 2> a;
dlib::matrix<double, 2, 2> b;
dlib::matrix<double> rez;
a = 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0;
b = 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0;
rez = a+b;
```

But this doesn't (assigning matrix multiplication result to previously defined matrix)

```
dlib::matrix<double, 2, 2> a;
dlib::matrix<double, 2, 2> b;
dlib::matrix<double> rez;
a = 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0;
b = 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0;
rez = a*b;
```

Matrix multiplication result can be assigned, but only if I assign the result to new dlib::matrix.

```
dlib::matrix<double> rez = a*b;
```

How can I make dlib::matrix multiplication work, so that I can assign the result to previously defined dlib::matrix?

Using (MinGW.org GCC Build-2) 9.2.0; Win10 and Visual Studio Code

Actual error is slightly longer, here is the summary:

```
In file included from ...\dlib-master\dlib\matrix\matrix.h:17, from kalman_filtr.cpp:3:
...\dlib-master\dlib\matrix\matrix_op.h: In instantiation of 
'struct dlib::matrix_traits<dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_pointer_to_col_vect<double> > >':
...\dlib-master\dlib\matrix\matrix_exp.h:130:51:   required from ...

... required from here
...\dlib-master\dlib\matrix\matrix_op.h:20:35: error: invalid use of incomplete type 
'struct dlib::op_pointer_to_col_vect<double>' typedef typename OP::type type;
```

Comment: the question is how to make `rez = a+b;` work?

Comment: `a = 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0;` if this works (as I think it works) it's probably the scariest code (principle of least surprise) I have seen this week.

Comment: @RichardCritten Eigen has similar abdominations from the time before list initialization was a thing. Indeed scary

Comment: I know that initialization looks bad, but that is just a test code created to show the problem. I can new line every matrix row, but for the sake of code length I didn't. I haven't found any other ways to initialize the matrices, let me know if there is a nicer way. @RichardCritten

Comment: @RichardCritten That's kind of the something-new-every-day [thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30508562/4944425) I wish I haven't learned today...

Comment: @AllanRääk Sorry if I gave the impression that I was criticising your question, that was definitely not my intention.  The question is well written, coded and with good examples.  I was just commenting about the features of the library you are using.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  You can most definitely say `rez = a*b;`.  It will put the result of multiplying a with b into rez.